# How to make arraList empty if the ajax response is error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, datatable

I have a empty arrayList initialized which is **var selection11Data = [];**.I am getting data from AJAX call as:

```
var selectionId=trData.selectionId;
            console.log("here");
            $.ajax({
                url : A_PAGE_CONTEXT_PATH + "/form/api/getSelectionAuditGroup/" + selectionId,
                method : "GET",
                dataType : "json",
                success : function(response) {
                    console.log("response here is");
                    console.log(response);
                    if(response.msg== "error"){
                        selection11Data =[];
                        $('#selectionWithAuditorGroupTable').hide();
                        alert("Selection Id"+selectionId+"is not assigned to any group");
                    }
                    else{
                        selection11Data = response;
                        $('#selectionWithAuditorGroupTable').show();
                        selectionWithAuditorGroup.rows.add(selection11Data).draw();
                    }

                }
            });
```

If the response is getting data,then it is populated in dataTable.But,if the response "msg" is error,then data table is hidden and in this instance i am hiding my dataTable and want to empty the arraylist `selection11Data`. But,it is not getting empty and when I get new data,then still the arrayList  contains the old data plus the new response data.At this instance i only need the new response data.How to empty this arrayList as i tried to clear arrayList if the response is error:

```
selection11Data =[];
```

Comment: can you explain clearly with example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
    var selectionId=trData.selectionId;
                console.log("here");
                $.ajax({
                    url : A_PAGE_CONTEXT_PATH + "/form/api/getSelectionAuditGroup/" + selectionId,
                    method : "GET",
                    dataType : "json",
                    success : function(response) {
                        console.log("response here is");
                        console.log(response);
                        if(response.msg== "error"){
                            selection11Data =[];
                            $('#selectionWithAuditorGroupTable').hide();
                            alert("Selection Id"+selectionId+"is not assigned to any group");
                        }
                        else{
                            selection11Data = response;
                            $('#selectionWithAuditorGroupTable').show();
                            selectionWithAuditorGroup.rows.add(selection11Data).draw();
                  //arraylist gets empty now
                           selection11Data =[];
                        }

                    }
                });
```